# Looking for an elegant way to store table data

Tags: c#

First post here :)
Relatively new to C# coming from C++ originally.
I'm currently working with table binaries that use the following format:

```
struct Table
{
Int32 rowCount;
Int32 columnCount;
customString columnNames[columnCount];
Int32 columnTypes[columnCount];
// Followed by the rowdata, where each type is different based on the columnType (0 = Int32, 1 = float, 2/3 = customString, 4 = Int64
};

struct customString
{
Int16 len;
char str[len]; // There is no null terminator
};
```

Due to the variable sizes of the strings I cannot define a struct for each table and cast.
All tables have different column names too. I'd like to be able to parse every single table in this format and easily be able to read all struct members. How should I go about this without filling in 240 struct members manually for each table?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: use `string`s and `System.Collection.Generic.List<T>`s? instead of arrays of char/int?

Comment: If you're going to use c#, learn to think c#. You're thinking c++ and that's not helping here.

Comment: This seems a lot like reinventing the wheel by biting stones into shape with your teeth. What are you trying to achieve? There are most likely much easier or more natural ways to do it. -- for example by using the [DataTable class](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable).

Comment: The save as Xml.  Use ds.WriteXml("flename", XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema) and the read method ds.ReadXml.

Comment: @Corak I am basically using a BinaryReader to read all the data correctly, but I then want to return it as an object and cast it to a predefined struct so I can read it correctly.

Comment: Don't. Convert the data and use a Database. There is probably no reason why you should reinvent the wheel. Stand on the shoulders of giants.

Comment: It would be more helpful if you describe a bit more the underlying problem. How are those binary files structured, and what do you need to do with the data?

Answer (score 1):

this might not be  to helpful but i would take a closer look at the data in the binary file to break down what and how to present/ hold you data.

the table struct could be much easier build with list for your rows and a row can have in turn list for fields and on the field level you can do all the hard work with figure out the type of the data and what else you need to keep track of.

Again this isnt a soluction ist only an suggestion because what you show us isnt a "final" stage i guess.

regards

Markus